# How to display a contribution page in a drupal block (NOT USING WEBFORM)

Tags: drupal, contribution-page

Normally Webforms would be a go-to solution but I have an urgent need and it is lacking recurring contributions + a few other necessities.

I have a contribution page and would like to put in panels or a drupal block.  I realize I can display a drupal block on a contribution page, but is it possible to display the page (no header, footer, etc.) in a block using an API call?  I know hooks are used when civicrm creates a page but I'm looking to do this in a drupal block (without something crazy like an iframe?

Comment: well if you're desperate, might it work to iframe it?

Comment: possibly.  I don't think I'm that desperate :)  I also need to set some javascript so getting a bit nasty that way. Will probably use drupal blocks on form (and document here when I can.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it'll work, no. Normally this might be done with `&snippet=1`, but it looks like that has a different meaning on contribute pages:

- http://d45.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?id=1
- http://d45.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?id=1&snippet=1

Comment: I'd love to see CiviCRM's Contribution API solid enough that we could build donation and other forms without having to use the built-in forms (which means dealing with HTML_QuickForm & Smarty if you want to diverge from CiviCRM's defaults). We run into this frequently, but getting enough energy behind it to address the required work never seems to come together ... how can we make it happen?